# After editing my wordpress website's footer copyright credites using My Custom Functions plugin, my site is down

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, storefront

I am making a wordpress store using storefront theme named [Pakoutfit.com](http://pakoutfit.com/).

I tried to edit its footer credentials using [My Custom Functions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-custom-functions/) plugin and using this plugin I run following code,

```
add-action( 'init' , 'custom_remove_footer_credit' , 10 );

function custom_remove_footer_credit(){
    remove_action( 'storefront_footer' , 'storefront_credit' , 20 );
    add_action( 'storefront_footer' , 'custom_storefront_credit' , 20 );
}

function custom_storefront_credit(){
    ?>
    <div class="site-info">
    &copy; PakOutfit <?php echo get_the_date( 'Y' ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

I do that following this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgQH3ZbR2E4),

Now when I tried to open my site or even its wp-admin panel it says,

> This page isn’t working
>   pakoutfit.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

I dont know that in which file My custom Functions plugin make changes so that I can reverse them.

I am using godaddy domain name and hosting.

I am new in this field. Please help me to make my site live again. Thanks

Comment: `add-action` should probably be `add_action`

Comment: But how can I change this code when i cant access my wp-admin panel?

Comment: You need to upload original function file to your theme using cpanel.

Comment: You should be able to access your files using ftp. With a tool like FileZilla.

Comment: `add-action` should DEFINITELY be `add_action`... undefined function no doubt.

Comment: Can you access cpanel? Change using file editor through that, or via FTP

Comment: It's dangerous using WP built in editor without other access if changing PHP and not jsut HTML / CSS

Comment: Yes I can access cpanel and i can edit using file manager

Comment: But I dont know which file to edit. I see functions.php file but I dont file functions that I added.

Comment: If there is an error in add_action then how can I remove that error. Where can I file that line through my file manager?

Comment: Can you access log files through cpanel? The log file might show file and line of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modification to your site should be made via a WordPress child theme. Do not edit core theme files: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Using your FTP or cPanel login, locate the file where you made the changes and remove them. That will restore your site.

Once you have your child theme installed and activated, and your function to the **child theme** *functions.php* file.

Be sure to change this:

```
add-action
```

To this:

```
add_action
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know in which fi8le  My Custom Functions plugin make changes.

Comment: Right, in that case disable the plugin. Sorry, I thought you added it to the theme files. You can disable this via the cPanel, delete or rename the plugin directory ***my-custom-functions**

Comment: Glad to help you!